# lightning:isUrlAddressable cache issue

Tags: cache, isurladdressable

I'm using a url button to redirect to a lightning component which has been implemented using `lightning:isUrlAddressable`.

The url button to redirect on lead is as : `/lightning/cmp/c__componentName?c__leadId={!Lead.Id}`

But the leadId when I try to obtain in `Init` is cached and hence getting the previous leadId instead of the current `LeadId`.

How to get to get the current leadid instead of getting cached value??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is the issue with `lightning:isUrlAddressable` It's not refreshing the view.

To resolve this Use `change` `aura:handler` of `pageReference` to call the same init method.

**Example**

```
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
 <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.init}" />
```

or else you can also refresh your view using `force:refreshView` event

```
  <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.reInit}" />

  reInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sarvesh. This works :)