# CurrentPageReference points to wrong reference on second open of LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

In an Aura component embedded on an Account record page, I have a button which navigates to a Lightning Component Tab using the following code:

```js
    const navService = component.find('navService');
    const pageReference = {
      type: 'standard__navItemPage',
      attributes: {
        apiName: 'MyLWC',
      },
      state: {
        c__recordId: recordId,
      },
    };
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

In my LWC referenced by my Lightning Component Tab, I have the hack needed to capture the current page reference:

```js
  currentPageReference;
  @wire(CurrentPageReference)
  setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
    this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
    this.checkForStuffToBeLoaded();
  }
```

The first time I click my button and I open the Lightning Component Tab, the page reference is set correctly to be my new tab with the correct URL and apiName and the `c__recordId` set properly. In my LWC, I can do this:

```js
   checkForStuffToBeLoaded = async () => {
       ...
       console.log(this.currentPageReference.attributes.apiName);
   }
```

The first time the component opens and this code runs, it logs "MyLWC" as expected.

Then if I **close** the Lightning Component Tab, and click on the button on the same Account page again, the **second** time the new tab opens, the **page reference is the originating account page, not the new tab**.

This also happens **any subsequent time** I click the button, including on different Account pages! As in, the above code logs `undefined` as there is no `apiName`, and instead `currentPageReference.attributes.objectApiName` is set to `Account`, even though I'm on the Lightning Component Tab LWC.

#### Fixes I've Tried

I've tried adding `@track` over `currentPageReference` in the LWC and it had no effect

I've also tried forcing different state on every Lightning Component Tab load, as in:

```js
    const pageReference = {
      type: 'standard__navItemPage',
      attributes: {
        apiName: 'MyLWC',
      },
      state: {
        c__recordId: recordId,
        c__random: Math.random()
      },
    };
```

The behavior still persists with the wrong page reference loaded in the LWC even though the URL is correct

Edit 2: This also appears to be an issue with navigating to an Aura Component with the LWC embedded. As in, if I create an Aura Component and then navigate to it this way:

```js
    const pageReference = {
      type: 'standard__component',
      attributes: {
        componentName: 'c__MyLwcWrapperAuraComponent',
      },
      state: {
        c__recordId: recordId,
      },
    };
```

And in my Aura Component I have:

```html
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" extensible="true">
  <c:myLwc></c:myLwc>
</aura:component>
```

Then the CurrentPageRef is still wrong on the second tab load.

Comment: Looks cache issue... Here, not the same problem but maybe also gives an idea https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298932/lightningisurladdressable-cache-issue

Comment: @LuismaWhatakuai so far nothing about my question seems like a caching issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why the CurrentPageReference gets set to the wrong tab on the second open of the LWC.

My current workaround is creating a wrapping Aura Component that passes its own pageReference to the LWC, as in:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" extensible="true">
  <c:myLwc pageReference="{!v.pageReference}"></c:placemat>
</aura:component>
```